# Open/close menu issue; on mobile and desktop/laptop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have attached a part of my code. I'm trying to get my fixed navbar working correctly. Right now, when I click the menu button, it works almost perfectly.

There are 2 issues that arise from the menu:

1. When not fully scrolled up to the top, when I click the menu button it jumps to the top instead of opening the menu (on mobile). But if scrolled all the way up, it will open the menu.
2. If on desktop/laptop, it will open the menu **AND** be forced to the top. I think if I could fix this, it would fix the mobile issue as well.

**There are not any 'href = #' that would be causing this issue, at least that I could find**

Any idea how to fix this?

```js
function menuChange() {
 "use strict";
    /****** Variables *****/
    
    
    // Burger link & image
 var burger = document.getElementById("burg");
    // Individual drop down elements; home, inventory, etc.
 var lines = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
    // Overall container; to make dropdown 'un-scrollable'
 var mainArea = document.getElementById("dropdownFreeze");
    // Cross link & image
 var cross = document.getElementById("xCross");
    // Background for dropdown & navigation
 var navList = document.getElementById("navList");
    // Social Media images & buttons
    var social = document.getElementById("navImage");

    
    // If menu is open, close it. If closed, open it
 if (burger.style.display === 'none') {
  burger.style.display = 'block';
  cross.style.display = 'none';
  
  navList.style.display = 'none';
        social.style.display = 'none';

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   lines[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  mainArea.style.position = 'relative';
  
  
 } else {

  burger.style.display = 'none';
  cross.style.display = 'block';
  
  navList.style.display = 'block';
        social.style.display = 'block';
        
  for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
   lines[j].style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  
  mainArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  

 }



}
```

```css
/********************************* 
    Max-Width: 
**********************************/
@media (max-width:1200px) {
  
/*********************************
    Mobile Size, Quick Phone Call Button
**********************************/
#quickcall {
    height: 35px;
    width: auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;

    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
#quickcall:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
main {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
    
/*****************************
    Buttons CSS
******************************/
.buttons {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
}
.buttons:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
.dropButton {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropButton:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
.dropButton:active {
    outline: none;
}
.dropButton:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#inventorySortContainer {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C4C4;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.sortByButton {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: .4em;
    right: .2em;
}
.sortByButton:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
.sortByButton:active, .sortByButton:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.sortOptions {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropDownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropDownContent a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
#viewInventory {
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#frontPageBlurb {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#frontPageBlurb p {
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

    
#navImage
    {
        display: none;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    
#navImage img
 {
  
  height:100px;
 } 


#navList
 {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
  display:none;
 }
 
 
.nav-item {
    
    position: relative;
 height:70px;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 
 
}
    
.nav-item a
    {
        display: block;
        height:100%;
    }

.nav-item:first-child
    {
        
    }
 
.nav-item li
 {
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  height:0px;
 }
.nav-item a li {
 
 
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
 
}
 

 
 



#lastNav {
    border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
}
.nav-item:hover a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fixed-nav {
    margin-top: -6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: .8em;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fixed-nav ul {
 
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin-top: 0; 
 
 overflow: scroll;
 
}
 
.fixed-nav li {
 
    box-sizing: border-box;
 
    
}
.fixed-nav li:hover {
    display: block;
    
}
.fixed-nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.fixed-nav ul li a:hover {
}
.fixed-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
#burg:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
#xCross:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
.hamburger {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 2px 15px 0 15px;
    color: black;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;

    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.cross {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 8px 15px 0px 15px;
 font-size: 70px;
    color: black;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    display: none;
}
.quickContact {
    display: none;
}
.mainImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#homeIcon {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bot: 10px;
}
#smallHomeIcon {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bot: 10px;
 left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#smallHomeIcon:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
#footer {
    height: 150px;
}
.footerInfo {
    
    
    margin-left:90px;
    text-align: left;
    
}
.footerMap {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footerPhone {
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
}
#footPhone {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
#footcall {
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
}
 
#dropDownSocial
 {
  text-align: center;
        
 }
#dropDownSocial img
 {
  height:32px;
  margin:20px;
 }
 
#dropDownSocial img:hover
 {
  opacity: .4;
 }
 
 
 
#socialMedia {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
#socialMedia img {
    height: 32px;
    margin: 20px;
}
#socialMedia img:hover {
    opacity: .4;
}
#footerSocial {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C4C4;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 10px;
}
#footerSocial h2
    {
        margin:20px 0;
    }
#asmLogo {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}
#asmLogoContainer {
}
#locationImage {
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#footAddress {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#footerLocation {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#clockImage {
    
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    
}
#footerHours {

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#labelContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#hours1 {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#hours2 {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#hours115 {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#hours97 {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#copyright {
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #C6C4C4;
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
}
.vehicle_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C4C4;
}
.vehicle_container:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.vehicle_MainImage {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.vehicle_Description {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bot: 10px;
    
}
.vTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.vTitleContainer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.vehicleInfoContainer {
}
.vehicleTitle {
    width: 100%;
}
.vehicleTitle h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.priceContainer {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
.vehiclePriceButton {
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    
}
.vehiclePriceButton:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#inventoryContainer {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#aboutUsContainer {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}
#missionStatement {
}
#missionStatement label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#contactForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#contactForm label {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#contactForm input {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#contactForm textarea {
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 100px;
}
#employerDisclaim {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#financeForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    /*border:2px solid black;*/
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#financeForm label {
}
#financeForm input {
}
#financeForm textarea {
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 100px;
}
#financeForm select {
}
#financeForm h3 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.financeDropdown {
    background-color: white;
}
.financeDropdown option {
    background-color: white;
}
#filterDesiredContainer {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
#filterDesiredContainer select {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
}
.financeInputs {
    width: 95%;
}
.financeLabels {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.horizontalContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.horizontalContainerCheckboxes {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.checkboxes {
    float: left;
    width: 4%;
}
.checkboxLabels {
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
#submit {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
#submit:hover {
    color: #FBB03B;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#submitFinance {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
#submitFinance:hover {
    color: #FBB03B;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#financeVehicleChoice {
    max-width: 95%;
}
#missionStatement {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C4C4;
}
.questions {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}
.answers {
    width: 100%;
}
.socialMediaLinks:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination {
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}
.pagination ul {
}
.pagination li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.pagination a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    color: black;
}
.pagination a:hover {
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    color: white;
}
.pagination a.active {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: black;
}
.paginationContainer {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.card {
    width: 75%;
    height: 505px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: .3s;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card::before, .card::after {
    white-space-collapse: collapse;
}
.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.card h4 {
    text-align: center;
}
.card h5 {
    text-align: center;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.cardDescriptionContainer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 205px;
}
#meetOurStaff {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#faqs {
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
}
#faqs h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#vehicle_description
    {
       
    }
    
.vTemplateImages {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
 
}
.vTemplateImages img {
    max-width: 100%;
 max-height:150px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
.vTemplateDisplayLeft {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 30px;
    bottom: .2em;
    left: .2em;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.vTemplateDisplayLeft:hover {
    /*color: #FBB03B;
    border: 2px solid #FBB03B; */
 
 background-color: #FBB03B;
}
.vTemplateDisplayRight {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 30px;
    bottom: .2em;
    right: .2em;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vTemplateDisplayRight:hover {
    /*color: #FBB03B;
    border: 2px solid #FBB03B;
 */
 
 background-color:#FBB03B;
}
.vTemplateMain {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.vTemplateInfo {
    width: 100%;
}
#carfax {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#carfax:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}
#mainArea {
 
}
.vTemplateLabel {
}
.vTemplateLabelContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #FBB03B;*/
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.vTemplateLabelDescription {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
.vTemplateLabelValue {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.priceDisclaimer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.priceDisclaimer button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: .3s;
}
/*Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: .3s;
}
.tab button.active {
    background-color: black;
    color: #FBB03B;
}
.tabContent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.tabContainer {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}
#disclaimer {
 
 font-size: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    
}
.comLinks {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.comLinks button {
}
.comLinks a {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.comLinks a:hover {
    color: #FBB03B;
}
.comLinks button:hover {
    color: #FBB03B;
}
.vTemplateLower {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#filterButton {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C4C4;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#filterButton button {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    outline: none;
}
#filterButton button:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#stateList, #stateList2, #stateList3, #stateList4 {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#stateList li, #stateList2 li, #stateList3 li, #stateList4 li {
    margin-top: -1px;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
#stateList li:hover, #stateList2 li:hover, #stateList3 li:hover, #stateList4 li:hover {
    background-color: #FBB03B;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.submit {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border-color: black;
}
    
#inventoryReturn
    {
        width:95%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top:60px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        text-align: center;
    }
#inventoryReturn a
    {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        color:black;
        
    }
#inventoryReturn:hover
    {
        opacity: .6;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px black;
    }

    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Used Cars|Tempe Dealer|Arizona Specialty Motors</title>
<meta content="Search Used Cars in Tempe at Arizona Specialty Motors to find the best car deals in Arizona." name="description">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/asmStyles.css">
<script src="js/myJava.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Top Navigation Div -->
<div id="topNav">
  <nav class="fixed-nav"> 
    <!-- Quickcall allows users to directly call ASM while the screen is adjusted for mobile-->
    <input id="quickcall" type="image" src="images/phoneIcon.png" alt="Call Us"/>
    
    <!--Buttons for Hamburger menu -->
    <button id="burg" onclick="menuChange();" class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
    <button id="xCross" onclick="menuChange();" class="cross">&#735; </button>
    
    <!--Navigation Links --> 
    
    <ul id="navList">
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="inventory.php">
        <li>Inventory</li>
        </a> </div>
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="https://extranet.dealercentric.com/CreditPlus?AssociateID=122567&AssociateTypeID=4000&P=GPIS&video=speed">
        <li>Finance</li>
        </a></div>
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="contact.php">
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        </a></div>
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="about.html">
        <li>About Us</li>
        </a></div>
      <div id="lastNav" class="nav-item"><a href="reviews.html">
        <li>Reviews</li>
        </a> </div>
      <div class="" id="navImage"> <a href="index.html">
        <li><img src="images/asmOriginalLogo_V4.png" alt="Arizona Specialty Motors"/>
          <div id="dropDownSocial"> <a href="#"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/fbLogo.png" alt="Facebook"/></a> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/arizona-specialty-motors/"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/In-Black-128px-TM.png" alt="LinkedIn"/></a> <a href="#"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/instaGlyph.png" alt="Instagram"/></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/az_specialty"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/twitterLogo.png" alt="Twitter" /></a> </div>
        </li>
        </a> </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="dropdownFreeze">
  <main id="mainArea"> 
    <!-- Main image on home page, eventually will be slider of pictures-->
    
    <div class="mainImageContainer"> <img class="mainImage vTemplate_image" src="images/gtr.jpg" alt="GT-R"/> <img class="mainImage vTemplate_image" src="images/weShip.jpg" alt="We Ship!"/> <img class="mainImage vTemplate_image" src="images/gtr2.jpg" alt="GT-R 2"/> <img class="mainImage vTemplate_image" src="images/gtr3.jpg" alt="GT-R 3"/> </div>
    <!-- View Inventory Button-->
    <div id="viewInventory"> <a href="inventory.php">
      <button id="inventoryButton" class="buttons" type="button">View Our Inventory</button>
      </a> </div>
    
    <!--Front page text info -->
    <div id="frontPageBlurb">
      <p> Arizona is the best place in our great Nation to buy a vehicle from! Our great weather helps keep vehicle condition excellent. We are dry year-round, so there is no corrosion from moisture, ocean air or chemically treated roads. <br>
        <br>
        These conditions can wreak havoc on vehicles not just aesthetically, but mechanically and electronically as well. </p>
    </div>

  </main>
  
  <!-- Footer Section -->
  <div id="footer">
    <footer>
      <div id="footerSocial">
          <h2>Follow Us on Social Media!</h2>
          <img id="asmLogo" src="images/asmOriginalLogo_V4.png" alt="LogoFooter" />
        <div id="socialMedia"> <a href="#"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/fbLogo.png" alt="Facebook"/></a> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/arizona-specialty-motors/"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/In-Black-128px-TM.png" alt="LinkedIn"/></a> <a href="#"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/instaGlyph.png" alt="Instagram"/></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/az_specialty"><img class="socialMediaLinks" src="images/twitterLogo.png" alt="Twitter" /></a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footerCombo">
        <div class="footerInfo">
          <div id="footPhone"> <a href="tel:+14804543844"><img class="footerPhone" src="images/phoneIcon.png" alt="Call Us"/></a> <a id="footcall"  href="tel:+14804543844"> 480-454-3844</a> </div>
          <div id="footerLocation"> <a href="#" ><img id="locationImage" src="images/mapLocation_Icon.png" alt="Find us at"/></a> <a id="footAddress"  href="#">1625 E Weber Dr <br/>
            Tempe, AZ 85281 </a> </div>
          <div id="footerHours"> <img id="clockImage" src="images/clock_icon.png" alt="Our Hours are"/>
            <div id="labelContainer" >
              <label id="hours1"> Monday - Saturday </label>
              <label id="hours97"> 9AM - 7PM </label>
              <label id="hours2"> Sunday </label>
              <label id="hours115"> 11AM - 5PM</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footerMap"> <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Arizona+Specialty+Motors/"><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?autoscale=1&size=300x200&maptype=terrain&key=AIzaSyDeJdb79cYUi58cl3hm1lctYvvshqBmASQ&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Clabel:1%7CArizona+Specialty+Motors" alt="Google Map of Arizona Specialty Motors"></a> </div>
      </div>
      <div id="copyright">
        <label >Copyright &copy; 2017 Arizona Specialty Motors </label>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run it in the snippet, it seems to jump to the top ***and*** open the menu.

Comment: Sorry if I didn’t describe it correctly. That’s how it works on desktop/laptop and I would like to fix it. I don’t want it to jump to the top